# Reading Configuration in Web API Code and Framework

Tags: c#, .net, webapi

I am working on a Web API, I started in ASP.NET Core (.Net Core) but needed to integrate some .NET Framework assemblies. I changed the Web API project to be ASP.NET Core (.NET Framework). When I read from appsettings.json in the .NET Core version of the API it works fine. When I do this in the .NET Framework version I get an initialised but unpopulated object.

My class looks like this:

```
namespace TfsCommon
{
    public class MySettings
    {
        string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

appsettings.json looks like this:

```
  "MySettings": {
    "Name":  "Name Here"
  }
```

Startup code to populate the object:

```
services.Configure<MySettings>(Configuration.GetSection("MySettings"));
```

This all works fine in ASP.NET Core (.NET Core) Web API. The ASP.NET Core (.NET Framework) Web API does not populate the object.

For reference these are the Project Templates I am using:

.NET Core

[image]

.NET Core with .NET Framework support

[image]